# How to enable keyboard keys for "please select row message" alert box in jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid

If row is not selected and delete row command is issued in jqgrid,

```
Please select row
```

message appears.

How to allow user to close this message by enter and esc keys and set focus to jqgrid after it ?

Currently mouse click must used to close this message box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the problem by replacing the statement

```js
$("#jqg_alrt").focus();
```

which is found directly after

```js
$.jgrid.viewModal("#"+alertIDs.themodal,{gbox:"#gbox_"+$t.p.id,jqm:true});
```

to the

```js
$("#"+alertIDs.modalhead+">a.ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close").focus();
```

or

```
$("#"+$.jgrid.jqID(alertIDs.modalhead)+">a.ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close").focus();
```

in the `jquery.jqGrid.src.js`. It will follows that "Close" button in the message header is selected and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will close the dialog

[image]