# Alert message using viewModal function in Jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm trying to implement a simple alert message using jqgrid and a custom nav. buttom.
All I wanted to do is when the button is clicked, it shows an alert if no row is selected(just like the default buttons that already work).

here's the code:

```
  onClickButton : function () { 


                    var line = $('#grid-list').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                    var grid = $('#grid-list');
                    var grid_id = grid[0].id;

                    if ( !line ) {
                        $.jgrid.viewModal("#alertmod",{gbox:"#gbox_"+grid_id,jqm:true});
                        $("#jqg_alrt").focus();
                    }
                    else {
```

Any suggestion??
thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error in your code is the usage of `"#alertmod"` instead of `"#alertmod_grid-list"` where `grid-list` is the id of the grid.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/DisplayCustomConfirmationDialog.htm) demonstrate the fixed code. It uses the following code of `onClickButton` callback:

```js
onClickButton: function () {
    var idSelector = "#alertmod_" + this.p.id;
    $.jgrid.viewModal(idSelector, {
        gbox: "#gbox_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.p.id),
        jqm: true
    });
    $(idSelector).position({
        of: "#" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.p.id),
        at: "center",
        my: "center"
    });
    $(idSelector).find(".ui-jqdialog-titlebar-close").focus();
}
```

In the above code I changed position of the Warning additionally and changed the focus so that one can close the box by pressing of <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (like described in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9975978/315935)).